# Can I get my iTerm key-combos working in tmux?

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux, escape-characters, iterm

I have some shortcut keys defined in iTerm, and I use them for key-mappings in Vim.

For example, I map `Ctrl-Enter` to send a `^[O2P` escape code, which I then use to define a `Ctrl-Enter` key-mapping in my Vim:

[image]

```
set       <F13>=O2P
map       <F13> <C-CR>
inoremap <C-CR> <C-O>o
```

It works in a regular iTerm session, and in a screen session, but it *not* in a tmux session. How can I fix this to work with tmux? I'm transitioning away from screen and really enjoying tmux aside from this hangup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by adjusting the escape codes to watch for in my `.vimrc`.
I still wish I had a better understanding of how all this works, and why the sequence sent by tmux differs from what's sent outside of tmux, but this got everything working:

```
if &term =~ "screen"
  set  <F13>=[1;2P
  set  <F14>=[1;2Q
  set  <F15>=[1;2R
  set  <F16>=[1;2S
  set  <F17>=[1;5P
  set  <F18>=[1;5Q
  set  <F19>=[1;5R
  set  <F20>=[1;5A
  set  <F21>=[1;5B
elseif &term =~ "xterm"
  set  <F13>=O2P
  set  <F14>=O2Q
  set  <F15>=O2R
  set  <F16>=O2S
  set  <F17>=O5P
  set  <F18>=O5Q
  set  <F19>=O5R
  set  <F20>=[1;5A
  set  <F21>=[1;5B
endif

" use some unused function key codes to
" make special key combos work in terminal
map  <F13> <C-CR>
map! <F13> <C-CR>
map  <F14> <S-CR>
map! <F14> <S-CR>

map  <F15> <C-Space>
map! <F15> <C-Space>
map  <F16> <S-Space>
map! <F16> <S-Space>

map  <F17> <C-BS>
map! <F17> <C-BS>

map  <F18> <M-Tab>
map! <F18> <M-Tab>
map  <F19> <M-S-Tab>
map! <F19> <M-S-Tab>

map  <F20> <C-Up>
map! <F20> <C-Up>
map  <F21> <C-Down>
map! <F21> <C-Down>
```

Comment: You haven't got any news on this and still do use this very solution?

Comment: @AS my solution has evolved somewhat, and I moved it into a plugin. I'm also mostly using Linux these days though, so I haven't tried my latest version in iTerm. You could give it a try though: https://github.com/ivanbrennan/iota/blob/eb6409db09f7b547f769dfd0a00de4396e7af14c/plugin/iota.vim