# Bash: mapping backward-delete-char to a different key

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, inputrc

In bash, is it possible to map `backward delete` not to physical `<Backspace>` key but to some other key?

I.e., `<F18>` has the following escape sequence `[1;5Q`, and I tried adding the following to my .inputrc:

```
"\e[1;5Q": backward-delete-char
```

...but unfortunately with no success. Thus, I wonder, is it possible at all?

Comment: It "should" work: if your keyboard really sends that string (which you should verify).  Actually, `\e[1;5Q` doesn't look like a possible `<F18>` (what terminal type is this?).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, by verify you mean something like `cat`? Then yes, it does echo that code. Anyway, it's not a physical key, actually. As you surely know, in modern terminals (like iTerm on OS X) you can define your own [escape sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154501/can-i-get-my-iterm-key-combos-working-in-tmux) for a key or a keys combination. So, I've done that, and now I'm trying to make it work in bash (as it already works in Vim). But somehow - as described above - with no success, unfortunately. Any suggestions, may be? Thanks!

Comment: Since it works-in-Vim, I assume you got the escape character mapped.  But that (literal `\e` versus escape character) is a detail that might go awry, since your sentence mentioning `<F18>` has no escape character.

Answer (score 1):

In iTerm2 add the following binding (to send hex codes) on `<F18>` keydown: `0x1b 0x5b 0x31 0x3b 0x35 0x51`.

The issue is that your test with `cat` is misleading. Here's the proper test: `cat | xxd`. Try before and after adding the hex code rule.

```
0x1b : escape byte (rendered as ^[)
0x5b : [
0x31 : 1
0x3b : ;
0x35 : 5
0x51 : Q
```

These are the bytes your inputrc is expecting.